# How to Configure Hudson to send email when port 25 is blocked

Tags: hudson

i am running Hudson on Windows7 box and hosted on tomcat server 7.0

when building the project gives me below error

any thoughts?

Cheers
Sri

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 10.20.27.xx, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)

at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)

at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.send(Mailer.java:524)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a different port.
Most SMTP servers also accept port 587.